# Set table column widths to content size? Or set a specific width px?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 and I currently have a table with about 12 columns.  I want the table to be scrollable horizontally.  For some reason, it is making the columns super small so the content is stacked... is there any way to fix this?  I have tried changing the width of the th elements but it does nothing.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      ......
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      .......
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div class="table-responsive">
```

Comment: I actually have that above the table but didn't include it in my code snippet.  It made the table scrollable but didn't do anything in terms of the column widths

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it by adding a `white-space: nowrap;` onto the TH and TR elements so that the columns will just be the size of the content.